# Dragging based on margin-left, margin-top, instead of top, left, using jQuery UI Dragger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

How can I drag items based on their margin-top, margin-left, instead of the default top and left properties, using jQueryUI Dragger.

Comment: I think you can't do that easily

Comment: Alternatives would help!